# How to check if someone is comming thru a port

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

I want a python program to check if someone is trying to come thru a certain port and IP and if so t will run this code:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto('\xff'*6+'\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55'*16, ('192.168.0.255', 9))
print "Attempted to wake host"
```

it will try to wake up another computer with is a certain mac address. the `\x00\x11` is the mac address. The `192.168.1.255` is the broadcast address. these are not my addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this server.
It will listen all connections to your computer on given port

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('',2232))
s.listen(1)
while 1:
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   conn.close()
   #do something here
   print "Someone connected"
```